# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<library> error while compiling (without sudo)

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I'll share with you my problem:

Basically I need to compile a tool (Freebayes: https://github.com/ekg/freebayes) in a cluster running rhel fedora 6.5 where I do not have sudo permissions.

When I compile with 'make' it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [libhts.so] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gspirito/freebayes/SeqLib/htslib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gspirito/freebayes/SeqLib'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gspirito/freebayes/SeqLib'
make[1]: *** [../SeqLib/src/libseqlib.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gspirito/freebayes/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It should mean that it cannot find liblzma.so, in fact if I run 'locate liblzma.so' it gives me this:

```
/usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0
/usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0.0.0
```

The liblzma.so is in a folder in my home (es: /home/usr/packages/lib), which I already added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the .bashrc file 
(export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/gspirito/packages/lib:/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH).
And also to the C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH.

I searched for a solution and in many forum it is suggested to link the two files like so:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0 /home/usr/packages/lib/liblzma.so.0
```

But I do not have permissions to do that.

I thought about changing my Makefile in order to make it look for libraries in my /home, but I have no experience in that. This is my Makefile:

```
all: vcflib/Makefile log
    cd src && $(MAKE)

wbamtools: vcflib/Makefile log
    cd src && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.bamtools

log: src/version_git.h
    wget -q http://hypervolu.me/freebayes/build/$(shell cat src/version_git.h | grep v | cut -f 3 -d\  | sed s/\"//g) &

src/version_git.h:
    cd src && $(MAKE) autoversion
    touch src/version_git.h

vcflib/Makefile:
    @echo "To build freebayes you must use git to also download its submodules."
    @echo "Do so by downloading freebayes again using this command (note --recursive flag):"
    @echo "    git clone --recursive git://github.com/ekg/freebayes.git"
    @error

debug:
    cd src && $(MAKE) debug

install:
    cp bin/freebayes bin/bamleftalign /usr/local/bin/

uninstall:
    rm /usr/local/bin/freebayes /usr/local/bin/bamleftalign

test:
    cd test && make test

clean:
    cd src && $(MAKE) clean
    rm -fr bin/*

.PHONY: all install uninstall clean test
```

How would I change it to tell it to look for -liblzma in /home/usr/packages/lib/ ?

Thanks a lot to anyone willing to respond.

Comment: Use the *full path* to the library?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm very new to this, could you suggest me where and how I should put the full path to the library in the Makefile?

Comment: Instead of using (for example) `-lsomelibrary` use the full path as in `/root/path/to/libsomelibrary.so`.